# Why was my question closed as "opinion based" when I'm asking how to solve a specific issue in a specific framework in a specific language?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen, opinion-based

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Highlighting the SEND button in MFMessageComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045448/highlighting-the-send-button-in-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller)

I asked a specific question on how to highlight a UI component within a predefined `UIViewController` in Swift for iOS. I gave background to what I have done, what I have tried, and what I think the solution might be. I then ask how to solve the issue, as I can not find sufficient evidence or code examples in the documentation.

I'm not sure why this is classed as opinion based. The Stack Overflow help page suggests posting here, as I'd rather not have to wait 5+ days for it to enter the re-opening queue after I've edited it (slightly). Can anyone help?

Comment: Opinion-based is a *weird* close reason for that question, I agree. However, I think the question is lacking some code that would allow others to reproduce the problem exactly as you are seeing it. That would help to contextualize it, and narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: I agree that it is not opinion based. I believe the uncertain tone used in the first revision of your question might have tripped reviewers. Example: "_I have looked into the UIAppearance protocol, but the options here seem very limited and do not help._" and "_Can anyone suggest a solution?_".

Comment: Most people who ask questions are uncertain of the solution. It's concerning if uncertainty in the phrasing used by the asker would trigger people to vote to close those questions as opinion-based, @AbdulAzizBarkat!

Comment: @CodyGray quite true, but with my limited understanding that is the only reason I can come up with the reason of the closure being "Opinion Based" as the first statement I pointed out is the only part which even remotely looks like opinion based to me. Perhaps it may have been only one close vote for "Opinion Based" and the other two might have been for "Lacks details or clarity" and "Needs debugging details" which would make much more sense here (Don't know what exactly happens if all the close reasons are different).

Comment: Two votes for opinion-based; one for "needs details or clarity". I agree that hiding the breakdown is a misfeature.

Comment: I... have to concur that this is quite bizarre that this got 2 "opinion-based" votes. While I can understand that asking "*anyone*" might trip it, it's far easier and quicker to reword it into a more proper question like "Is it possible to ..." or "How to ...". The wording is not even worse than "How does anyone do it?" which is more prominent as "opinion-based"...

Comment: the question lacks of focus and should **not** be opened at all

Comment: @nbk Would you care to tell us what focus it lacks, and what information it would need to have added in order for you to consider reopening it?

Comment: @CodyGray The user has to show that he tries one or more solutions with code and where it fails, to ask i want and how can i,  lacks  of focus

Comment: It's not a debugging question. It's a how-to question. The description of the problem seems adequate to me.

Comment: There is no code necessary for that question. I'm not an iOS developer (or user), but even I know exactly what they're asking.  `MFMessageComposeViewController` is a well-known, standard component (or whatever terminology they use). From what I know of it, it's possibly a case of there being no real good "official" solution for it – e.g., no explicit public API, but people have found hacks – so maybe those vote reasons were considered the closest to "not really (supposed to be) possible, technically", without having to get into the same old discussion about it again for the umpteenth time.

Comment: @nbk: Many "how to" questions *aren't* valid because they're too trivial or poorly researched.  (e.g. the kind of thing that would be assigned as homework for novices.)  *those* kinds of questions always need an attempt.  But more interesting questions don't necessarily.   Nobody is saying that being a "how to" question without an attempt makes it on topic, just that it doesn't *rule out* being on topic.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question here discussed is as any other homework question, where the lack of self studying and trying your best is mostly closed

Comment: @nbk: I didn't say otherwise - I haven't done more than glance at this actual question, and am not familiar with the techs involved so I don't have an opinion on it.  I just wanted to point out that being a how-to question alone doesn't necessarily make it off-topic, so if you're going to argue that a question should be or stay closed, you should be more specific.  (When I think a question is too trivial but still clear, I usually only downvote, not close vote.  Outside of actual clearly-homework questions, I don't think I should decide that nobody else should answer just because it's boring.)

Comment: @nbk: Although for boring/trivial questions, I do relax my standards for being a duplicate, and will be willing to close if I can find a duplicate that covers the relevant basics that the question is missing.  (Again, I'm not talking about this question specifically.)

Comment: Adding some context as someone who does understand the question, there's no need to see the code samples. This is a very minimal class - typical use is `new thing(); thing.foo = bar; thing.doYourThing()` and there substantial functionality hidden in parent classes (millions of lines of implementation code). The ansewr is "what you're looking for doesn't exist" and that's not documented anywhere it's just general general platform knowledge. Perfectly reasonable question IMHO, and likely someday what he's hoping to do will be possible. I don't see why it should be closed.

Comment: OK, so the post was re-opened, thanks Guys :), but has now been closed again as it "needs details or clarity".  Has someone got a vendetta against me?  I can't think how to add details or clarity to the post (that haven't been added either by myself, or the helpful folks who helped tidy up the original).  PS this isn't a homework assignment that I can't be bothered to research, it's an app that should have been submitted to the App Store last week and I'm spending my weekend trying to respond to the concerns of some non-tech-savvy testers (who are my target customers!)

Comment: @JonH nah, your post just got in the crossfire of two groups with different views on whether to use "lack of visible research" when considering question closure, don't sweat it too much. Personally, I don't find it problematic, and it's quite clear, but others may disagree. Note that there are limits in place to prevent abuse so those who acted on the post once cannot recast their votes - your post was closed by 3 different users (check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68045448/timeline)).

Comment: @MikeM. "no explicit public API, but people have found hacks" - you're completely right. Apple's built-in alerts, mail composers, share sheets, etc are notoriously hard to customize. It's probably to maintain a standard across the entire platform though.

Comment: Relevant: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: It seems this was a mistake. With only 3 close votes necessary for a closing, a wide spectrum of views and hundreds of closings every day, this is bound to happen quite often. It's nothing special. What is special is the intensity of the meta effect (this question isn't really worth a score of 24). If everyone who got a question closed would open a meta question about it, this way of correcting mistakes wouldn't work. Also we don't really need to feature it in the HMP queue so often (just came from there). It's really already decided and doesn't need more attention.

Comment: Almost 66% of the questions in the last 30 days are unanswered but there are people dedicated to close and delete questions for all sort of subjective reasons instead of trying to answer or to improve them. This is supposed to be a Q&A site.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA Just because someone typed text into the question box doesn't automatically make it a Q that should have an A on [SO]. This is supposed to be a Q&A site, not a help-desk.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA "This is supposed to be a Q&A site." You're right. And even this question here does not have an answer yet (it may not be possible though). It highlights one thing though. For a good Q&A site you need two things, people with interesting questions and people with knowledge and the will to answer the questions. If there is only one of the two things - no Q&A site. I wouldn't generalize from this one example though. It doesn't mean that every question gets closed even though they all should remain open.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA - I don't know what you are basing your analysis on. A simple [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425440/percent-of-truly-unanswered-questions-including-deleted?Offset=1) shows that only 37% go *truly* unanswered. SE's definition of "unanswered" is unreliable as users tend to "forget" to accept answers. Even if so, questions being *timely* answered is not a good metric because it assumes that we have to answer the newest stuff (which is half garbage anyway) disregarding questions with existing answers (which many of us prefer).

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA it also does not account for some questions being spam seeds, for blatantly off-topic ones, and those asked by non-English speakers. It also uses a very small timeframe. If you up this to 12 months - a more appropriate timeframe for measuring success - we get only about 25.58%, an even lower number.

Comment: I just gave your question the third, reopening reopen vote and upvoted it ! ;)

Comment: Whether the question should be closed or not – don't mind. But can people please stop upvoting just because? The currently 41 upvotes is *insane*.

Comment: Folks, to whoever voted for closing as "unclear" - please, stop making the post a battleground, really. It is a clear question if nothing else (original close reason discussion aside), please make it stop and allow this to go away.

Comment: Comments are still a way of getting answers to questions which have been closed. The politics of getting the question opened again takes more time than posting answers in comments, which help OP faster and gets the job done.
The are many people who can't even be bothered to read the whole question or suggest edits to make the question good enough to receive answers. They don't care if the question would benefit anyone with a similar mindset with a valid problem that needs to be solved.
Don't sweat it, just ask again, even if it means asking here. It will eventually get noticed, and answered.

Comment: I hate the whole culture of closing and downvoting - it's the worst thing about this site. They're desperately looking for ways to make the site more friendly to newcomers, and yet they still allow someone who asks a question a bit too tentatively to be slapped in the face with a closure or downvote. You learn in time how to game the system by asking your questions in the right way, but until you've done so, it can be a rough ride.

Comment: @MichaelKay No, asking questions the right way is not gaming the system, it's **following the rules**. Questions that get downvoted and closed also often do not follow those rules. If you don't like the rules, you're free to go elsewhere.

Comment: @Zimba Just because you aren't willing to follow the rules, doesn't mean you or anyone else gets to. If you have a problem with them, go elsewhere.

Comment: No one has mentioned the insidious consequence of forcing a question that shouldn't have been closed to spend at least 5 days unanswerable until it enters the reopen queue (unless it gets intercepted by observant users, the meta effect, or a diamond moderator) through *no fault of the asker*. The process is necessary for questions that needed to be closed, and edited to form, but actively harmful to questions that never should've been closed. The vast majority of my binding reopen votes are used to counteract this (at least, whenever I'm on the site anymore).

Comment: Anyway I'm speaking from personal domain knowledge that this question shouldn't have been closed. I bet had JonH simply provided some sample code and a couple of screenshots without the exposition, people would've asked in the comments "Why do you want to do this?" The exposition is all the details and clarity you need. The only thing that would materially benefit the question now is a mockup as one comment there suggests. I don't think sample code is needed. Then someone can answer "no, Apple has good reasons for not allowing this but it's a shame it results in the sort of UX you now face."

Comment: @BoltClock Arguably closeable as a duplicate; e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766022, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11455734. Certainly not the first time someone's asked how to change that UI.

Comment: @Mike M.: Yeah. Make that "shouldn't have been closed as anything but a duplicate".

Comment: @Mike M... Not exactly duplicate, but similar to 26766022 I agree (except I don't want to send automatically).  While thinking about Clashsoft's comment on the original question, I have found a suitable workaround that is not mentioned in any other posts (introduced in iOS6, so not relevant to 11455734, but relevant to 26766022 and my original question).  My question is closed (again) so I can't answer it though!  I had thought that, if it were closed and linked as a duplicate of 26766022, I could add an answer to that post, but then realised that my "fix" doesn't answer 26766022.

Comment: @BoltClock "no, Apple has good reasons for not allowing this but it's a shame it results in the sort of UX you now face." Are you sure it's not possible? That's the problem with negative answers. To judge their quality one has to basically show what is possible and show that the desired feature is not a part of what is possible. A simple answer saying "It's impossible, believe me." might simply get downvoted.

Comment: The open/close war on this question becomes a bit embarrassing - maybe we should just make our mind up here on meta and then act accordingly. I blame especially that this meta question is featured by the HMP algorithm. It really doesn't need to be. It's just about a single question of millions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I never said that. Read my comment again. What I said is similar to what most people are saying. ¿Why wasting time trying to close or delete a question with no **clear** reason to be closed or deleted? What I suggest, considering this is a Q@A site to HELP people with answers, contrary to what you say, is exactly that: Try to answer it or at least try to improve it. Else, do nothing. Let the people who understand the question, deal with it.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA Honestly, I am quite happy about every close-worthy question that is closed because it allows me to actually find the answerable, on-topic questions. Because, believe it or not, *I'm here to answer questions*. Is the closing process perfect and infallible? No, it's not. Is it outrageously bad and unreliable? Doesn't look like it to me. I'd much rather lose a pearl than drown in sand.

Comment: I find it very interesting that this meta question is +90/-7, the main question is +42/-10 and that it's still closed. Moderation and the voting system seem to be on different paths these days.

Comment: @Alex it's because most interested parties exhausted their close / reopen votes. After all, the limit is one vote of a type per post.

Answer (score 32):

When voting to close a question, you are presented with a list of options to choose from as the reason for closing. These options aren't always a good fit to the voter's actual reason. Furthermore, some of the options are "hidden" behind a menu system where you must first select one choice and then select another. The layout and content of the reasons has changed many times over the years. In short, it is not a very user friendly system.

Either for that reason, or out of laziness, many people will select a reason which doesn't accurately reflect the reality. Subsequent voters will see the choice made by previous voters and will often just choose that - either (again) out of laziness or from an assumption that the first voter got it right.

In your case, as suggested in the comments, the question was closed for the wrong reason.

Comment: So your anwers boils down to _"People want to close questions, and if they can't find a valid reason to do so, they'll click a random one"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster That has often (but not always) been my experience. I frequently encounter closed question which legitimately ought to be closed but for which the reason for the closure is clearly wrong.

Comment: The other problem is that the reported close reason assumes unanimity between the votes.  Sometimes, I'll vote to close a question with Reason A but the other two people think Reason B is right, and it gets reported as if I agree with them when (quite often) I don't.

Comment: And if all 3 closers choose different reasons, just one of them will be shown, so 2 out of 3 closers are incorrectly claimed to have closed for that reason.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, if all 3 users use a different reason, I'm pretty sure the banner shows a generic "not on-topic as described in the help-center" reason. Not that this is particularly better or anything, just thought I'd mention it. It also doesn't apply to dupe closures IIRC; the duplicate wins even if it's the only vote cast for it.

Comment: I'm assuming this answer is simply *descriptive*, rather than *prescriptive*, but I'll note here anyway: **this is *doing it wrong***. You, as a close-voter, are responsible for the actual reason that you choose. If you're too lazy to click the right reason, then stop voting. If you can't find a reason that matches, then don't close the question. That's a clue it shouldn't be closed. Downvote it instead.

Comment: In my experience the "opinion based" is the most problematic option. It almost seems that people voting closing select this because the question should be closed in their opinion (that is, they misunderstand what this option is supposed to do). In addition, I would set the bar much higher for closing "opinion based" because some questions do not have a clear winner but maybe 2 or 3 possible solutions. Closing the whole question because there cannot be a clear winner solution seems worse than having a question with 2-3 possible options even if selection between those were opinion based.

Comment: Maybe instead of closing a question for being "opinion based", just show a warning about it being opinion based? That way question could have multiple different answers and community could still vote which is the best solution even if none of the options are great or can solve the problem as a whole. Maybe require 100+ reputation to answer opinion based question?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen opinion based is when people are soliciting opinion, if the question can only be answered with opinions not based on anything concrete/objective. It's not that hard. The thing is that people pick anything, rather than defaulting to unclear.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen All close votes are cast based on the *opinion* of the close voter. Same for every other type of vote. Only a small percentage of questions on Stack Overflow have only *one* correct answer; having multiple possible correct answers is not what "opinion-based" means.

Comment: @TylerH I agree that having multiple possible correct answers is not what "opinion-based" means. However, many people casting close votes seem to think that if the question doesn't have one clear solution it's opinion based and they will case close vote with that reasoning. Of course, the way question is put matters also; for example, if the question is basically "Which one is better, X or Y" you get easily closed opinion-based even though answer could be "X because Y causes security vulnerability Z".

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen "*However, many people casting close votes seem to think that if the question doesn't have one clear solution it's opinion based and they will case close vote with that reasoning.*" Citation needed. Your example that follows is still opinion-based; besides, whether "security vulnerability Z" is even a concern is a matter of opinion, depending on who is reading the question and what their personal threat matrix is. Such questions need to be provide *objective* metrics. It's fairly uncommon that a question can use the word "better" and still be on-topic.

Comment: I agree that "Which one is better, X or Y" and "X because Y causes security vulnerability Z" is an opinion based question and answer. For that not to be the case, the answer should not start with "X because". E.g. the question could be "Which security vulnerabilities are known to exist in Y but not in X?" in which case a similar, non-opinion based answer could be given (but the question might still be liable to be closed for other reasons e.g. being too broad).

Comment: This answer depicts the sad reality of the close vote community that has been built here.

Comment: @TravisJ Please do elucidate.

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen: A common (mis)use of "opinion-based" is when a question is asking the difference between X and Y (not necessarily which one is *better*, just if any difference exists), and someone uses that close reason to mean "They are functionally equivalent, so any difference is a matter of opinion" when it ought to be an answer instead. Came across one such close vote just [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955920/difference-between-nth-of-type1-and-first-of-type-pseudo-classes). People use that close reason this way on a daily basis.

Comment: However, in my experience, Meta disagrees whether or not a close reason can substitute for an answer. I can only say that I don't think it can. If we can be picky about whether content should be a question, answer or comment - we can afford to be picky about whether a close reason should've been an answer instead.

Comment: @Ian Kemp: Not all close voters understand the close reasons, or worse, use their votes responsibly. Many just want to see problematic questions closed, whatever it takes. See also dupehammer abuse. I don't know about robo-reviewers (though there are users here who **only process the close/reopen queues on Meta Stack Overflow and do nothing else on the entire network**), but I still want to blame the review badges for encouraging people who are not competent reviewers, to participate in review.

Comment: Perhaps the "Ask Question" form for should include a list of known problematic words such as "opinion", "best", "better", "appearance", "cool", "favorite", "feel", "attention", etc. If user enters any such words there should appear a warning or notice that reminds that "You should not ask for opinions but facts on this platform – consider formatting the question some other way." However, that should not prevent the user from sending the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question consists of two questions, i.e.

1. How do I highlight the send button ...

and

2. ... or access the button so that I can draw the user's attention to it?

While part 1 is not opinion based, part 2 seems to be. How a UI should be made to make the user focus on specific items are not something that we all can/will agree on. So I don't think it's completely wrong to close as "opinion based".

Comment: They're not asking "what is your favorite way to draw the user's attention to buttons". _That_ would be opinion-based.

Comment: @CodeCaster To me it's also opinion based to ask "How do I draw the users attention to UI item X". Person X may think solution A is good while person Y may prefer solution B.

Comment: No, "how to" is not opinion-based. I want to whack people in the face over the Internet who answer _"How to parse CSV?"_ with _"Use `string.Split(',')`"_, but that doesn't make the question opinion-based.

Comment: In other words, reading between the lines instead of parsing the question's words like a lexer, OP is asking _"How can I show the Send button to users instead of having it hidden by default, requiring them to take action to be able to click it"_. They are not asking about answerer's favorite way of showing buttons, be it blinking them, rendering arrows, dimming the rest of the screen or whatever. They are asking about _any_ solution.

Comment: So "**How to** make a good looking UI" isn't opinion based to you?

Comment: Not the part you bolded is; the "good looking" part makes it so.

Comment: @CodeCaster "...  be it blinking them, rendering arrows, dimming the rest of the screen.." Well, animated unicorns walking towards the send button would be the only solution (IMO of course)

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. They don't really care right now about the highlighting itself. They basically just want to know how to access a button in a system/external dialog.

Comment: ...No. The OP is clearly asking "How do I highlight the send button [*in order to*] draw the user's attention to it?" That's most certainly a *single* question, with a single stated task for a given purpose, not two open ended questions. You've misinterpreted their request.

Comment: The original question said "Can anyone suggest a solution to highlight the send button within the MFMessageComposeViewController, or access the button so that I can draw the user's attention to it?" Notice here that the "How do I" was edited in by me.

Comment: "You're misunderstanding the question." "You've misinterpreted their request" Sounds like the person who voted "Needs clarity" was close to the mark...

Comment: Interestingly, a question like #2 would be considered on-topic at [ux.se].

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me the request was: "How can I do 1, or (2) if that can't be done, are there any other solutions that closely approximate 1?"

Comment: @zcoop98 How can you simply ignore the **or** in the question and replace it with some text  that isn't at all in the original question? That makes no sense. Obviously you can turn the sentence into being one question by changing it but that's... cheating

Comment: Se second question is absolutely not opinion based. There are entire degree programs for effective UX design.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Many things about UX design would be fine at SO but some things are also opinion based. As an example just check the discussion that starts when SO changes the site.

Comment: @4386427 If SO site changes followed UI/UX design principles there wouldn't be nearly as much discussion

Comment: @4386427 I didn't ignore it at all. The "or" here is a clarifying aside, not indicative of a second question. The full quote is "*How do I highlight the send button within the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, or access the button so that I can draw the user's attention to it?*" The "or" here is between "highlight the send button" & "access the button", both of which are ways to "*draw the user's attention to [the button]*. The OP isn't asking to either "highlight" or "draw attention", that doesn't make sense– highlighting and access are *both* ways to draw attention in context.

Comment: @4386427 If anyone cheated here, you did, by omitting the bit between "or" and "so that I can draw...", because that's the part that clarifies it's not two questions in one, even if it may not seem important at first glance. OP isn't asking "how do I draw attention", they're asking "How do I do *A* or *B* so that I can draw attention?". That's why I subbed out the "or" altogether in my requote.

Comment: @zcoop98 That's exactly two questions! How do I do A? How do I do B?

Comment: @4386427 *That* is an understandable debate! I disagree that asking how to do both is close-worthy, but I understand. That's not what you presented above, however. "How do I highlight the send button" (your point #1) serves exactly *one* purpose: "draw the user's attention to it" (your point #2). The dichotomy you made in your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @4386427 To clarify why I still disagree; Even though you may be able to split "How do I do A or B to get C?" into two questions, both variants of "How do I do [A/B] to get C?" are still, at their core, about *getting C*. My assumption is that OP doesn't really care about knowing both A and B, and instead just wants to know how to get C, which is (likely) answerable, and on-topic. I don't think this assumption is a stretch in most cases.

Comment: Just about any programming question can be construed as multiple questions if you prefer to think of it that way. In my opinion we need more leniency than some people are willing to give. It's possible to have two separate sentences ending in question marks within a post that has a well-defined and cohesive nature. People here seem to be saying no more than: "Look at that! *Two* question marks!" In my opinion the post has a cohesive nature, and an answer to it could easily help other programmers.

Comment: @zcoop98 I agree with that last comment. And that's exactly my point. C is "so that I can draw the user's attention to it". So according to your comment the question is really "How can I draw the user's attention to it?". To me it's kind of opinion based what the best way to get attention to a UI item is.

Comment: @Gershy In the end the point is not whether it's two questions. It's whether some part of the question can be seen as opinion-based and therefore explain why some users (not me btw) voted to close as opinion based.

Comment: @4386427 The question isn't "how _should_ I draw attention to it", it's "how can I access the button (so that I can modify it)". "How can I access the button" is perfectly reasonable and not opinion based (you can run the code and see if you accessed the button or not, end of story).

Comment: @user3067860 So the way you read the question is that if OP could be told how to "access the button", OP already knows what to do to draw attention to it. In other words, the question could have been: "How do I highlight the send button within the MFMessageComposeViewController, or access the button".  Is that it?

Comment: @4386427 Yup. For example, an answer like "make the button flash" would not be at all helpful to the OP. But an answer like, "If you use xyz API call, you can manipulate how the button looks however you want." certainly would be.

Comment: @4386427, OP question seems to be (my rephrase) "Is it possible to make the send button more discoverable by users, by highlighting or otherwise? If so, how?" which is not opinion-based.

Comment: @justhalf To me the "otherwise" part of your rephrase is exactly what makes it opinion based. Person A could say "You can do X" but Person B don't think doing X is good and suggest doing Y which Person C doesn't like and so on.

Comment: I think others have mentioned this example as well, but: having multiple ways to do a task doesn't automatically mean it is opinion-based. I'm guessing what people disagree with is whether "drawing users' attention to the Send button" is an objective metric or not. To me it's objective enough to not consider it opinion-based. But I can see how others might consider it very subjective.

Comment: @justhalf "But I can see how others might consider it very subjective." That's more or less what my whole answer tried to convey to OP.

Comment: @zcoop98 BTW: Point taken about the missing words in the quote. Updated accordingly.